# How to avoid writing back the pages in mmaped-region to disks?

Tags: c++, mmap

I use memory mapping for a file, then I update its contents as if it's an array.

I found that during the updates the dirty pages are written back to disks incurring huge disk I/O, which I want to avoid.

I tried with **mlock** to lock the pages in memory. But it still writes back the dirty pages.

How can I achieve this? (I program in C++ @ Linux)

Comment: How often a page is written to disk?

Comment: That depends on the system's available memory size and the kernel's configurations. I just want to make sure that not a single page is written back to disks. :D

Comment: Well at some point if the system is limited on memory and it has to swap out some pages and if the page selected to be swapped out is one from your mmap it would be optimal ( and the correct way ) for the OS to just rewrite the page to the disk place from where it read it from. 
Sounds like it would be better just to allocate a buffer big enough and read that file to that buffer. Work with that. At the end just write the contents back to the file.

Comment: Linux dirty page cache is automatically flushed after a timeout, and you cannot tweak the behaviour except by changing the timeout for the whole system.  The timeout is controlled by the `sysctl` `vm.dirty_expire_centiseconds`.  This answer applies to the current kernel v4.19.  If anyone ever implements `UFFDIO_REGISTER_MODE_WP` for `userfaultfd`, I *think* you could get close to emulating what you want.  You could always do all the IO yourself to/from mlock()ed memory.  The `userfaultfd` feature would just let you detect pages you had not changed and skip them, or at least that's my hope.